# can not open xde.exe from its location in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0

Tags: android, xamarin, emulation, virtual

When I try to open "xde.exe" file I get the error message "the emulator cannot find a virtual machine with name default emulator"  as in the image below:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

and when I run my xamarin project from visual studio 2015 I face the following  error message "*xde.exe has stopped working*" 
so , can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please tell me what you want to achieve? Run an `Android` or `UWP` project?

Comment: I am trying to run android application on visual studio 2015 and  I get the error message "xde.exe has stopped working"

Comment: You can config a Android Emulator in Android Device Manager and use this Emulator to run your project. Have a look at these documents: [debug-on-emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/debug-on-emulator?tabs=windows#overview)  and  [device-manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=windows&pivots=windows).